# dynamically adding images to a ListView

Tags: android, image, sqlite, listview

I know this question sound familiar and you will tell me that I should find my answer if made a little search on it... but pls nothing is working for me!

I need a code that can add dynamically a specific image to each row content!

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = database.query("names", fields, null, null, null, null,
                null);

        dataSource = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, data, fields,
                new int[] { R.id.first, R.id.last });

        ListView view = getListView();
        view.setHeaderDividersEnabled(true);
        view.addHeaderView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, null));

        setListAdapter(dataSource);
    }
```

Comment: You have used sqlite as a tag, but didn't mentioned anything about using a database. You doesn't provide code for what you have tried and what doesn't work. You ask for code from us which isn't what this community supports. So try again and improve the question. Where are you stuck? What have you done so far?

Comment: i have a list view that contain a name and a last name.

Comment: i  want to a the persons country flag before the text(name,lastname)

Comment: Edit you question and add additional information like code snippets of your current solution.

Comment: What is the source of your images ? you can write the code with the default android icon as the country image and then replace the image code later.

Comment: i edited my questions...here's my code upthere

Comment: @AnthonyK What is the name of the images you want to display? Are they same for all rows?

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild guess here - because the question is really hard to understand.

You have a List of Objects that have

- A flag (image)
- name
- lastname

I would suggest using a custom listview adapter to fill a horizontal linear layout which holds an ImageView and two text views.

This presentation really helped me to get started with ListViews, and I would recommend watching it.

http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html